# Undefined item pushed in my array?

Tags: javascript, object

Im creating an object and pushing to an array this.reminders , but an undefined is also gets push why is that? This code will give me work `[ { description: 'Get to work in time', set_title: 'work related' }, undefined ]`

```
   var ReminderSet = function(set_name) {
        this.set_name = set_name; 
        this.reminders = [];
    };

    ReminderSet.prototype.add = function(reminder, title) {
        this.reminders.push(reminder, title);
        console.log(this.set_name, this.reminders)

    };

    ReminderSet.prototype.list = function() {
        console.log(this.reminders); 
    };

    var Reminder = function(description,set_title) {
        this.description = description;
        this.set_title = set_title;
        //Describes the reminder
    };

var work = new ReminderSet("work")
          .add(new Reminder("Get to work in time", "work related"));
```

Comment: well, your add method pushes in reminder and title, but your your code calls it with a new Reminder object, and no title ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `add()` method takes two parameters:

```
ReminderSet.prototype.add = function(reminder, title) { /*...*/ }
```

But you're passing only one (i.e. a `Reminder` object):

```
var work = new ReminderSet("work")
      .add(new Reminder("Get to work in time", "work related"));
```

This causes the second parameter to be undefined.